# dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?

Tags: dd, cloning, cat

I recently realized we can use `cat` as much as `dd`, and it's [actually faster than `dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492)

I know that `dd` was useful in dealing with tapes where block size actually mattered in correctness, not just performance. In these days, though, are there situations where `dd` can do something `cat` can't? (Here I would regard a less than 20% performance difference irrelevant.)

Concrete examples would be nice!

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2794049/23744) for one concrete example.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

In appearance, [`dd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) is a tool from an IBM operating system that's retained its foreign appearance (its parameter passing), which performs some very rarely-used functions (such as EBCDIC to ASCII conversions or endianness reversal… not a common need nowadays).

I [used to think](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-write-repeated-free-form-strings-to-a-file-as-fast-as-dd/11468#11468) that `dd` was faster for copying large blocks of data on the same disk (due to more efficient use of buffering), but this [isn't true](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492), at least on today's Linux systems.

I think some of `dd`'s options are useful when dealing with tapes, where reading is really performed in blocks (tape drivers don't hide the blocks on the storage medium the way disk drivers do). But I don't know the specifics.

One thing `dd` can do that can't (easily) be done by any other POSIX tool is **taking the first N bytes** of a stream. Many systems can do it with `head -c 42`, but `head -c`, while common, isn't in POSIX (and isn't available today on e.g. OpenBSD). (`tail -c` is POSIX.) Also, even where `head -c` exists, it might read too many bytes from the source (because it uses stdio buffering internally), which is a problem if you're reading from a special file where just reading has an effect, or from a pipe when the rest of the data should be left for another process to read. (Current GNU coreutils read the exact count with `head -c`, but FreeBSD and NetBSD use stdio.)

More generally, `dd` gives an interface to the underlying file API that is unique amongst Unix tools: only `dd` can **overwrite or truncate** a file **at any point** or **seek** in a file. (This is `dd`'s unique ability, and it's a big one; oddly enough `dd` is best known for things that other tools can do.)

- Most Unix tools overwrite their output file, i.e. erase its contents and start it over from scratch. This is what happens when you use `>` redirection in the shell as well.
- You can append to a file's contents with `>>` redirection in the shell, or with `tee -a`.
- If you want to shorten a file by removing all data *after a certain point*, this is supported by the underlying kernel and C API through the [`truncate`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/truncate.html) function, but not exposed by any POSIX command line tool [except `dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/how-can-i-edit-large-file/1305#1305):

  ```
    dd if=/dev/null of=/file/to/truncate seek=1 bs=123456  # truncate file to 123456 bytes
  ```

  (Many modern systems provide a `truncate` utility, however.)
- If you want to overwrite data in the middle of a file, again, this is possible in the underlying API by [opening](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) the file for writing without truncating (and calling [`lseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html) to move to the desired position if necessary), but only `dd` can open a file without truncating or appending, or [seek](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8852/is-there-a-search-utility-which-can-binary-split-search-a-large-sorted-sequentia) from the shell ([more complex example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place/11114#11114)).

  ```
    # zero out the second kB block in the file (i.e. bytes 1024 to 2047)
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/file bs=1024 seek=1 count=1 conv=notrunc
  ```

So… As a system tool, `dd` is pretty much useless, [even dangerous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial). As a text (or binary file) processing tool, it's quite valuable!

Comment: Accepted because I think it explains the gist of the other answers (`trunc` and `seek` being usable from `dd`).

Comment: One more special use: `dd` can read binary data from nonseekable file descriptors without potentially destroying unread data due to stdio buffering. See here for an example: http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html

Comment: @R..: Good point. While the GNU implementation is safe, others aren't.

Comment: GNU implementation of...? `head -c 1`?

Comment: @R..: Yes. In GNU coreutils 6.10, `head -c N` calls `read` and never goes beyond N. In NetBSD 5.1, `head -c` calls `getc`. In FreeBSD 7.4, `head -c` calls `fread`.

Comment: Can I interest you in copying the whole post [here](http://superuser.com/questions/692588/can-cat-be-used-to-clone-a-partition) on [SU] so we can point other posts to it as a duplicate. (Can't do that cross SE sites).

Comment: Any Bourne-like shell can open a file without truncating with the `<>` redirection operator (read-write, you can use the reading in place of seek if you want to write in the middle of the file). `ksh93` has seeking operators (`>#((...))`...).

Comment: I occasionally use `dd` for rescueing and repairing filesystems, partitions, labels and databases directly off the block layer. It is also valuable in case you need to closely inspect and binary process files that are so huge that you can't open them with any kind of tool in their entirety, then copying a single, smaller linear piece out of that file with `dd` is just more handy than even using `split`.

Comment: I use dd for pulling n bytes from the middle of a file or splicing n bytes into the middle of a file.

Comment: Coreutils `dd` also exposes O_DIRECT (etc.) to shell scripting, which I think is also unique.

Comment: Coreutils [`truncate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/truncate.1.html) allows truncating or extending files, thus eliminating another use of `dd`.

Comment: I had no idea cat could be faster than dd. This is revealing to me after all these years. Thank you :)

Answer (score 26):

No one has yet mentioned that you can use dd to create [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), though `truncate` can also be used for the same purpose.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse-file bs=1 count=1 seek=10GB
```

This is almost instant and creates an arbitrary large file that can be used as a loopback file for instance:

```
loop=`losetup --show -f sparse-file`
mkfs.ext4 $loop
mkdir myloop
mount $loop myloop
```

The nice thing is that it initially only uses a single block of diskspace, and thereafter grows only as needed (ext4 formatting of a 10GB file consumes 291 MB on my system). Use `du` to see how much disk space is actually used -- `ls` reports only the maximum size the file may grow to.

Comment: `ls -ls` shows you the sparse size.

Comment: Your command writes a useless byte to the file. `dd of=sparse-file bs=1 count=0 seek=10G` would be equivalent to `truncate -s 10GB sparse-file`. Confusingly enough, `truncate` and `dd` have exact opposite interpretation of `GB` vs. `G`...

Comment: @frostschutz: `man dd` says: `MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024` and so on. And `man truncate` says: `MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024`, so there is **no difference.** I use both `dd` and `truncate` from the GNU coreutils. You should do so, too! :-)

Comment: @erik: Thanks for the correction. If it wasn't changed recently I must've confused it with something else somehow.

Comment: @frostschutz: they're (both) the opposite of current SI-prefixes convention (standard?) of `Ki`/`Mi`/`Gi` for 1024 and bare `K`/`M`/`G` for 1000, maybe that's what you meant? It's unfortunate `dd` chose to interpret `B` (the _unit_) as its 1000-base SI "modifier", considering Bytes is (I believe) the only unit where a 1024 base might be used

Answer (score 24):

The `dd` command includes LOTS of options that cat is not able to accommodate. Perhaps in your usage cases cat is a workable substitute, but it is not a dd replacement.

One example would be using `dd` to copy part of something but not the whole thing. Perhaps you want to rip out some of the bits from the middle of an iso image or the partition table from a hard drive based on a known location on the device. With `dd` you can specify the start, stop and quantity options that allow these actions.

These options of `dd` make it indispensable for fine grained data manipulation whereas `cat`* can only operate on whole file objects, devices or streams.

*As noted by Gilles in the comments, it is possible to combine `cat` with other tools to isolate parts of something, but `cat` still operates on the whole object.

Comment: `dd` actually has nothing to do with low-level devices, it needs an entry in `/dev` like the others. You can copy a whole partition with `cat`, or a part of it with `tail +c $(($start+1)) | head -c $count`.

Comment: Of course. ;-) And when I feed a 1.6TB disk image into `cat | head | tail` to fetch the last few MBs the disk spin up will suck the moon in closer to earth.

Comment: @Gilles Sorry I did mean to acknowledge that my use of the term "low level" wasn't very good diction, although I was referring to data on devices, not devices. Perhaps "fine tuned data manipulation" would be better than "manipulating low level data".

Answer (score 11):

Override specific segments of a hard-drive with something is a common example. For example you might want to delete your MBR using this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1
```

Also you can create empty files with it (say for loop disk images):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=10mb.file bs=1024k count=10
```

Comment: As an aside, that second command is the fastest way that I know of to use up 10MB

Comment: @Kevin: Faster than `head -c`? Please share a [benchmark](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492)!

Answer (score 9):

`dd` is very useful for backing up the boot sector of a hard drive or other storage device (`dd if=/dev/sda of=boot_sector.bin bs=512 count=1` ) and then later rewriting it (`dd if=boot_sector.bin of=/dev/sda`).  It is similarly useful for backing up the headers of encrypted volumes.

`cat` might be able to be twisted into doing that but I wouldn't trust it on the rewriting part.  It's difficult to get `cat` to only read/write a certain number of bytes.

Comment: It's not _difficult_, it's actually _impossible_ with `cat` alone. But for that particular task you don't need `cat` at all, you could use `head -c 512 /dev/sda > boot_sector.bin`

Answer (score 8):

I recently had had cause to clone some multiple-100s-of-GB partitions for the first time in my linuxing history (c.f `cp -ar` or `rsync` which have served me well many times).  Of course I turned to `dd` 'cos everyone knows that's what you use... and was appalled by the performance.  A bit of googling soon led me to [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html), which I've used a few times now and works superbly well (much faster than dd).

Comment: **`ddrescue`** is great, especially for getting data out of failing disks.

Comment: To get good performance with `dd`, you'll have to set block sizes. E.g., `bs=1M`.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some dd tricks I've come up with over the years..

### **Cut-and-Paste on unfriendly tty or non-interactive mode bash**

If you're in a situation where EOF/^D/^F is not detected you can use dd to transfer text files to a host. Since it will stop reading after a specified amount of bytes automatically.

I used this as recently as last year during a security exercise where we were able to get non-tty shells on a remote host and needed to transfer files in.

In fact, I even did a couple binary files by base64 encoding them and using a slow, but reliable pure-bash base64 decoding script.

```
dd of=textfile.txt bs=1 count=<size_of_data_in_paste_buffer>
```

A super cool trick is that while dd is running, if you send it a USR1 signal, it will emit it's current status (bytes read, bytes per second..)

### **Universal throughput state filter**

I wrote this to act as a pure bash progress filter for any program that emits data through stdout. (Note: Pretty much anything will emit data through stdout - for programs that don't, you can cheat if they don't barf on you using /dev/stdout as a filename. But the idea is basically, every time you get X amount of bytes, print hash marks (like old school FTP when you had hash mode on)

(Note) The progress file thing is lame, this was mostly a proof of concept. If I redid it, I'd just use a variable.

```
 dd bs=$BLKSZ of=${TMPFILE} 2>&1 \
                | grep --line-buffered -E '[[:digit:]]* bytes' \
                | awk '{ print $1 }' >> ${PROGRESS} &

 while [[ $(pidof dd) -gt 1 ]]; do

        # PROTIP: You can sleep partial seconds
        sleep .5

        # Force dd to update us on it's progress (which gets
        # redirected to $PROGRESS file.    
        pkill -USR1 dd
        local BYTES_THIS_CYCLE=$(tail -1 $PROGRESS)
        local XFER_BLKS=$(((BYTES_THIS_CYCLE-BYTES_LAST_CYCLE)/BLKSZ))

        if [ $XFER_BLKS -gt 0 ]; then
                printf "#%0.s" $(seq 0 $XFER_BLKS)
                BYTES_LAST_CYCLE=$BYTES_THIS_CYCLE
        fi
done
```

### **slice-and-dice files using anonymous shell filehandles**

Here's an extremely pseudo-code example of how you can have a signed tar file that you can extract without errors by providing tar input through an anonymous filehandle - without using any tmp files to store partial file data.

```
generate_hash() {
    echo "yay!"
}

# Create a tar file, generate a hash, append it to the end
tar -cf log.tar /var/log/* 2>/dev/null
TARFILE_SIZE=$(stat -f "%z" log.tar)
SIGNATURE=$(generate_hash log.tar)
echo $SIGNATURE >>log.tar

# Then, later, extract without getting an error..

tar xvf <(dd if=$OLDPWD/log.tar bs=1 count=${TARFILE_SIZE})
```

The tl;dr is: I find dd to be incredibly useful. And these are just the three examples I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 6):

You can redirect some output content. It's particularly useful, if you need to write with `sudo`:

```
echo some_content | sudo dd status=none of=output.txt
```

Besides `sudo` it's equivalent to:

```
echo some_content > output.txt
```

or to this:

```
echo some_content | sudo tee output.txt > /dev/null
```

Comment: Good point. More at [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why I'm using `dd` is the fact that it will output statistics if you send it a `USR1` signal. So whenever I'm doing some long copying, such as writing an ISO file to a key or suchlikes, in parallel, I run:

```
~ watch -n10 killall -USR1 dd
```

This will have `dd` print the statistics every 10 seconds, something looking like:

```
1895740+0 records in
1895740+0 records out
970618880 bytes (971 MB, 926 MiB) copied, 2.46699 s, 393 MB/s
```

I'm not sure whether this is true for all POSIX `dd` or just the variant I happen to have.

Comment: `pv` does that (arguably) better

Comment: `dd status=progress` is also way more convenient than signals...