# Are there alternatives for `dd`?

Tags: files, utilities, dd, binary

What tools other than `dd` should I use to read and write files with truncation, seeking and skipping? `dd`'s command line options seem inconvenient and foreign and I don't like choosing between slow, but precise seeking mode (`bs=1`) and fast, but inflexible mode (`bs=4k` or whatever).

Are there more modern tools to read  555 bytes from one file (or pipe or socket or dev) from position 31337 and write them to the other file at position 128205 (using blocks 512+43), with or without truncation?

Comment: I still don't see what is wrong with `dd`.  You could always put a shell script wrapper around it if you don't like the interface.  [`dd` is in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html), which is a huge plus.

Comment: The main wrong thing is inability to seek to or skip fractional blocks. Second wrong thing that `status=noxfer` is not default and is broken and that I need `iflag=fullblock` (omit in some script => broken data).

Comment: You can combine fast-inflexible with slow-precise, e.g. like so: `dd bs=1M skip=TO_CHUNK count=1 | dd bs=1 skip=OFFSET`. It takes some arithmetic but a wrapper script can deal with that.

Comment: 1. `bs=1` => the whole pipeline is slow. For example I may want to dump video file starting from some exact frame. 2. "It takes some arithmetic" => not very suitable for oneliners and routine shell commands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days)

Comment: When your demands of functionality and performance get so stringent, I find it's time to start writing code in some systems programming language. (C by default on Unix, but pretty much anything else statically compiled would work as well.) The problems you're posing are dozen line programs.

Comment: **PSA: `dd conv=seek_bytes` will make `seek` work with byte precision.**

Comment: @i336_ dd: unknown conversion seek_bytes

Comment: @Trejkaz: A bit of digging turned up the following in http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS: "*Noteworthy changes in release 8.16 (2012-03-26) [stable]*" ... "*dd now accepts the ... seek_bytes oflag*". So you need **at least 8.16** for this flag to exist. I can see some distros having >6 year old coreutils. What distro are you using and more importantly what version are you on?

Comment: @i336_ multiple distros, and we're supposed to support any machine someone might want to SSH to.

Comment: @Trejkaz: That's a bit of a tricky scenario. The coreutils and other base packages have received lots of little updates in recent years, which somewhat fragments the predictability/consistency of "what'll always work in the field" given that lots of systems can indeed be very old. I'm curious what your specific use case is, but more to the point, it sounds like your best bet would be to open a new question to describe the bigger picture. (Of course I'd like a link to it)

Comment: @i336_ I think it just means that the safest option for us would be to avoid using a shell script and write a standalone statically-linked executable. I was just shopping around for alternatives because from time to time I hear about crazy stuff being possible directly in bash, and wondered whether direct file access might be one of those crazy things.

Answer (score 5):

There is the tool `ddrescue` (watch out, there is also `dd_rescue` which is a different program with almost the same functionality). It uses the more familiar syntax with the single dash for short or double dash for long options. From the man page:

```
   -i, --input-position=<bytes>
          starting position in input file [0]

   -K, --skip-size=<bytes>
          initial size to skip on read error [64 KiB]

   -M, --retrim
          mark all failed blocks as non-trimmed

   -o, --output-position=<bytes>
          starting position in output file [ipos]
```

Comment: `ddrescue - -` -> `Infile and outfile are the same.`, `ddrescue /dev/stdin /dev/stdout` -> `Infile and outfile are the same.`. Bad beginning of the story...

Comment: I just tried with `dd_rescue`. It throws a warning that the file (stdin) is not seekable, but proceeds. You can give it a try. However, `ddrescue` feels more full-featured and mature.

Comment: @Vi.: Don't shoot the messenger. `ddrescue` is right, pipes aren't seekable. If you want to start reading at a specific point in a file, you need to give it access to the file in question, not data piped from another program. Also beware that using pipes fights against this wish of yours for ultimate speed, since the only way to emulate seeking in a pipe is to read and throw away the parts you don't want to process. Seeking within an actual file is far more efficient.

Comment: Indeed, since the tool is designed for rescuing broken data, there is _no_ pipe capability. This is a bit of a shame when you want the flexibility of seeking through an input file but just want to pipe the result to stdout. For its intended purpose, though, it's great.

Answer (score 5):

[dcfldd](http://dcfldd.sourceforge.net/) is another dd alternative.   It doesn't address the OP's question about input/output seek flexibility, but may be useful to others arriving here via google search.

It's based on gnu dd, with the following additional features:

- Hashing on-the-fly - dcfldd can hash the input data as it is being
  transferred, helping to ensure data integrity.
- Status output - dcfldd
  can update the user of its progress in terms of the amount of data
  transferred and how much longer operation will take.
- Flexible disk
  wipes - dcfldd can be used to wipe disks quickly and with a known
  pattern if desired.
- Image/wipe Verify - dcfldd can verify that a
  target drive is a bit-for-bit match of the specified input file or
  pattern.
- Multiple outputs - dcfldd can output to multiple files or
  disks at the same time.
- Split output - dcfldd can split output to
  multiple files with more configurability than the split command.
- Piped output and logs - dcfldd can send all its log data and output
  to commands as well as files natively.

Answer (score 3):

A good alternative is `pv`.  Not only does it automatically calculate the most efficient block size, essentially speeding things up, but it also provides progress, among other things.  It's use is simple:

```
pv < /dev/sda > sda.img
```

It plays well with compression too.  A fast way to backup and compress a disk in one move is like so:

```
pv < /dev/sdb | pigz -9 > disk.img.gz
```

You can learn more [here](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).

Comment: Main expected feature is seeking in output and input files, which pv (pipe view) does not provide, as there is no seek for pipes.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use a dd pipe to accomplish this, without the performance penalty, without truncation or rounding errors, and with byte-level accuracy:

```
dd iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes skip=1234 count=42 | dd oflag=seek_bytes conv=notrunc seek=12340 of=test.bin
```

On the left side, dd will skip the first 1234 bytes and read exactly 42 bytes. It will perform with efficient sector buffering and alignment. Exactly 42 bytes will be read at offset 1234 with no rounding errors. On the right side, dd will seek past exactly 12340 bytes on the output and write only the 42 bytes it receives from the pipe. It will perform with efficient sector buffering and alignment. In the pipeline, the two dd instances will send+receive data in sector-sized chunks for good performance, except for the last few bytes which are handled properly.

Note that there is no oflag for count_bytes, so this pipeline is required!

Here is an example attempting to count only 2 bytes, but without the pipeline. Notice that extra data is consumed on the input and written to the output:

```
$ printf aaa | dd oflag=seek_bytes conv=notrunc seek=0 count=2 | xxd
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
00000000: 6161 61                                  aaa
3 bytes copied, 0.000158916 s, 18.9 kB/s
```

Comment: Add "iflag=count_bytes" to your example counting only 2 bytes, and it indeed only counts two bytes. So, I don't think the pipe is needed. (It makes sense that dd takes in the same number of bytes as it sends out.)