# How can you trim files using the command line?

Tags: files, dd, sparse-files

What is the console equivalent of the following Python code:

```
target = file("disk", "w")    # create a file
target.seek(2*1024*1024*1024) # skip to 2 GB
target.write("\0")
target.close()
```

Maybe some dd incantation? The idea is making a file with the apparent size of 2 GB for use e.g. in virtualization.

```
kvm disk -cd whatever.iso #Only allocate space as necessary
```

Comment: `dd` is the only traditional tool that exposes the `seek` system call (see [dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532) but there are other ways to skin this cat on typical current unices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, just use `dd`; but as you mention the use of KVM virtualization, you might consider using `qemu-img`:

```
qemu-img create -f raw disk 2G
```

It does the same as the `dd` command in the answer of Chris Down, effectively.

Regardless of what command you use, for use in virtualization, I would strongly suggest using `fallocate` to pre-allocate blocks in order to prevent fragmentation and increase performance.

```
fallocate -l 2G disk
```

It's not available on all platforms and filesystems, though. This will not write zeroes, but just assigns blocks to the file, rather than doing that on-demand later every time it has to extend the file.

Comment: Is the quote a typo?

Comment: @badp yes, fixed.

Comment: `qemu-img` and `dd` both perform **one** system call to set the file size (ftruncate), but will perform a lot more to load themselves and the libraries they're linked to. And, in that regard, `dd` is going to be a lot more effective than `qemu-img` (which is a lot larger and is linked to far more libraries). GNU `truncate` is going to be even more effective. `dd` also has the advantage of being ubiquitous. Good point about `fallocate` though.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I totally second your comment. I've edited my answer to point out that `qemu-img` is just an obvious alternative in the use of KVM virtualization.

Answer (score 14):

You can create a sparse file like this with `dd`:

```
dd of=file bs=1 seek=2G count=0
```

```
$ du file
0       disk
$ du --apparent-size file
2097152 disk
```

Comment: Also, `2G` is a GNU extension to `dd`. You can use `bs=1024 seek=2097152` if you don't have GNU `dd`.

Comment: Heh, `G` is an extension, and it's not supported by OpenBSD's version of dd... but, `M` and `K` are supported, so maybe `seek=2048M` is a bit more readable, depending on what platforms you're targetting

Comment: You should read from /dev/zero: if=/dev/zero

Comment: @DanielFanjul Why? There is absolutely no difference, no bytes are written.

Comment: @ChrisDown Because /dev/null contains no data when you read, but /dev/zero contains infinte zeros. Oh, count=1, the number of bytes to write must not be zero.

Answer (score 7):

See also the GNU `truncate` command:

```
truncate -s 2G some-file
```