# Use dd to backup disk image within an OpenVZ container

Tags: ssh, backup, dd, xen, openvz

I want to use `dd` to backup the disk of an OpenVZ VPS in addition to traditional cold tar backups. Because I may need to migrate to a different VPS provider.

From end user point of view, OpenVZ containers are **folders** on the host (similar to LXC). If I am not wrong, OpenVZ uses common file system so containers (virtual environments) are just directories (isolated by chroot).

Within the container, `/` uses a block device called `/dev/simfs`, I wonder if I can use dd to backup the whole disk image over SSH.

Technically I don't see any problem, but I haven't done it myself, just not 100% sure and confident. I have done the same thing for Xen and VMware VMs, it worked fine.

For Xen

`ssh root@vps "dd if=/dev/xvda " | dd of=~/backup/xen.img`

Does it work for OpenVZ, anyone has tried this before?

`ssh root@vps "dd if=/dev/simfs" | dd of=~/backup/openvz.img`

Comment: I don't have access to OpenVZ machine. What does `file -s /dev/simfs` say? Is it a filesystem? Can you do `mkdir /mnt/root ; mount -o ro /dev/simfs /mnt/root`? If so, dd might work as well. If not, dd won't work either.

Comment: Also you should be aware that without some kind of snapshot functionality, dd'ing the live root parititon of a server will produce an inconsistent/damaged image.

Comment: @frostschutz I am aware of the fact. I am just testing the if it works. Because later on I may need to migrate to a different VPS provider (I'll do traditional cold tar backups and do a `dd`). LVM or Btrfs snapshots work better for backups if I host the containers myself;-)

Comment: `file -s /dev/simfs` => `/file -s /dev/simfs 
/dev/simfs: writable, executable, no read permission` Not sure what exactly it means.

Comment: [Useless use of `dd`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days) → `ssh root@vps cat /dev/xvda >~/backup/xen.img`

Comment: @Gilles Cool! I use `cat` more often than `dd`, e.g. zeroing out virtual HDDs. But `dd` still works well when creating swap files;-)

Comment: `dd` is a swiss army knife, don't call it useless...

Comment: And if you have no read permission, you can't use either `dd` or `cat`. You might have to work on the filesystem layer.