# Fast Way to Randomize HD?

Tags: encryption, dd, random

I've read about how to make hard drives secure for encryption, and one of the steps is to write random bits to the drive, in order to make the encrypted data indistinguishable from the rest of the data on the hard drive.

However, when I tried using `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda` in the past, the ETA was looking to be on the order of days.  I saw something about using `badblocks` in lieu of urandom, but that didn't seem to help a whole lot.  I would just like to know if there are any ways that might help me speed this up, such as options for `dd` or something else I may be missing, or if the speed is just a limitation of the HD.

Comment: Change your block size to something more friendly toward hard drives. `dd bs=1M` for example.

Comment: What speed were you getting? It takes a while to write an entire 3TB (for example) HDD. Also check `iostat -kx 10` to see what busy % on the drive is.

Comment: `shred -v -n 1 /dev/overwritethis` is fast. It's about the only case where `shred` is actually useful for something.

Comment: @derobert: I can't really say for sure how fast it was, but I left for a few hours, came back, and it was around 10% complete for my 500G internal HD the first time I tried this.  Thanks for the "iostat" tip btw

Comment: @Patrick: I tried bs=4M sort of blindly, since I saw that on the guide for how to put the Arch CD on a usb.  It helped slightly, but it was still pretty slow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda`, or [simply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days/12538#12538) `cat /dev/urandom >/dev/sda`, isn't the fastest way to fill a disk with random data. Linux's `/dev/urandom` isn't the fastest cryptographic RNG around. [Is there an alternative to /dev/urandom?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6440/is-there-an-alternative-to-dev-urandom) has some suggestions. In particular, OpenSSL contains a faster cryptographic PRNG:

```
openssl rand $(</proc/partitions awk '$4=="sda" {print $3*1024}') >/dev/sda
```

Note that in the end, whether there is an improvement or not depends on which part is the bottleneck: the CPU or the disk.

The good news is that filling the disk with random data is mostly useless. First, to dispel a common myth, [wiping with zeroes is just as good on today's hardware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/why-is-writing-zeros-or-random-data-over-a-hard-drive-multiple-times-better-th/10474#10474). With 1980s hard disk technology, overwriting a hard disk with zeroes left a small residual charge which could be recovered with somewhat expensive hardware; multiple passes of overwrite with random data (the “Gutmann wipe”) were necessary. Today even a single pass of overwriting with zeroes leaves data that cannot realistically be recovered even in laboratory conditions.

When you're encrypting a partition, filling the disk with random data is not necessary for the confidentiality of the encrypted data. It is only useful if you need to make space used by encrypted data indistinguishable from unused space. Building an encrypted volume on top of a non-randomized container reveals which disk blocks have ever been used by the encrypted volume. This gives a good hint as to the maximum size of the filesystem (though as time goes by it will become a worse and worse approximation), and little more.

Comment: Gutmann is a myth in its entirety, I don't think it's actually ever been done for a 1980s hard disk either. The irony is that with drives getting smarter, you actually should use random data nowadays to make sure the drive is forced to write, rather than free sector (trim) or compress data. Zeroes are only good if they're actually written.

Comment: So should writing with /dev/zero be ok then?

It sounds like that is the case from what you're saying, including this link I found (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk#Unrandom_data)

Comment: @mellowmaroon Yes, `cat /dev/zero` is almost always enough. It's only not enough if you want to hide how much space is free on the encrypted volume.

Comment: I guess what I'm really wondering is how much of a risk I am at by allowing the amount of free space to be visible.  Sorry to keep on asking.

Comment: @mellowmaroon It's pretty much useless. An eavesdropper will know that you have at most X MB of data (and possibly a lot less, because formerly-used-but-now-free space is indistinguishable from used space), so what? Also the location of the free space might reveal the filesystem type (superblock copies); that's rarely a concern (it's typically exposed in the cleartext `/etc/fstab`, unless you've encrypted the root partition, and even then there aren't such a large number of plausible options).

Comment: @Gilles The problem I ran into in Ubuntu 13.10 is that `openssl rand` seems to have an upper limit on the number of bytes it will generate. If you exceed that limit, e.g. 'openssl rand 810000000000`, then no random output is generated. Only a brief "help" text is printed. I'm trying to random (pretty much) fill a 3TB hard drive. Not sure if there is a way to get `openssl` to produce that many random bytes.

Comment: @Gilles Also, even if it would work, `openssl rand` is still too slow on my admittedly "ancient" core 2 duo desktop. Piping `openssl rand` to the `stdin` of `dd` appears to fill the drive at around 30 MB/s. If I instead use `if=/dev/zero` on the `dd` command I get (initially) around 150 MB/s. Drat. (But of course that is still much better than `/dev/urandom`. ;-) )

Comment: For irrational John's upper limit problem, 810 billion bytes comes out to around 754 GB. How about partitioning your disk into multiple 700-GB partitions, then running the `openssl rand` command on each partition in reverse starting from sda5 or whatever and working backwards to sda1 and finally sda?

Comment: @jia103 I have no idea what problem you're trying to solve here. Fragment the task so that it can be spread over multiple sessions/days/whatever? Why use partitions in reverse order from their number?

Comment: Thanks.  This ran at about 500GB/hr on a Ryzen 3 @3.5GHz (FreeBSD).  My filesystem compresses on-the-fly so /dev/zero takes a VERY long time to fill a disk; I wanted uncompressible data to fill the unused space on a 6TB disk for qualification and this did the job.

Answer (score 8):

You can get OpenSSL to encrypt `/dev/zero` with a randomized password, giving decent pseudorandom data very fast (if your CPU supports accelerating it).

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt < /dev/zero | dd of=/dev/sda
```

You could pipe this through `pv` to get progress/ETA. The commands I'm running right now (in a root shell) are:

```
DISK="sda"
DISKSIZE=$(</proc/partitions awk '$4=="'"$DISK"'" {print sprintf("%.0f",$3*1024)}')
apt-get install pv
openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -nosalt \
  -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" \
  < /dev/zero |
  pv --progress --eta --rate --bytes --size "$DISKSIZE" |
  dd of=/dev/"$DISK" bs=2M
```

I got this idea from [this answer](//serverfault.com/a/415962/67295), after having the same problem as [irrational John](/users/17742/irrational-john), who [commented](/q/72216/172088#comment169427_72238) on Gilles's answer above. This increased my wipe speed to my new RAID array from 11 MB/s to around 300 MB/s, taking what was going to take a week down to 10 hours.

I'll add that you should be able to use
`openssl rand #of_bytes` rather than the more complicated `openssl enc ...` statement above, but there is a bug which will allow `ssl` to produce only 16 MB of output. (This bug has been filed, Jan 2016.)

And, as per the answer to [this question](/questions/253466/parallelize-openssl-as-input-to-dd), and continuing to assume that the CPU is the bottleneck, it may be possible to increase speed further by running multiple parallel `openssl` processes on separate cores, combining them using a FIFO.

Comment: Not sure the edit was necessary. Other answers to this question suggest `openssl rand`.

Comment: Benchmark: `dd if=/dev/urandom`: 18MiB/s, `openssl enc`: ~180MiB/s, `fio`: 169MiB/s, `openssl rand` no support > 754GB. Note that if you also want auto-size calculation, use: `openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt </dev/zero | pv --progress --eta --rate --bytes --size $(</proc/partitions awk '$4=="sda" {print sprintf("%.0f",$3*1024)}') | dd of=/dev/sda bs=2M`. Beware, `sda` is present twice in this command.

Answer (score 6):

The openssl did not seem to work for me. I got "unknown options" and other issues with the provided solutions. So I ended up going with the program fio.

```
fio -name="fill" -ioengine=libaio -direct=1 -bs=512m -rw=write -iodepth=4 -size=100% -filename=/dev/md0
```

Which seems to be taking 3 hours to do 19TB across 24 HDDs. So roughly 1,800 MB/s

```
smp-016:~ # fdisk -l /dev/md0
Disk /dev/md0: 18890.1 GB, 18890060464128 bytes

smp-016:~ # fio -name="fill" -ioengine=libaio -direct=1 -bs=512m -rw=write -iodepth=4 -size=100% -filename=/dev/md0
fill: (g=0): rw=write, bs=512M-512M/512M-512M/512M-512M, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=4
fio-2.2.10
Starting 1 process
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)] [2.7% done] [0KB/1536MB/0KB /s] [0/3/0 iops] [eta 03h:01m:11s]
```

I hope this is actually random data. The man page says fio "Default: fill buffers with random data." http://linux.die.net/man/1/fio

I'm not doing it for secure/encryption purposes, just trying to be sure my later read tests are actual data and not just 0's. This same fio command could be used for SSD/NVMe preconditioning. As just using /dev/zero can lead to disk level compression "cheating" how much is actually written. Although I would add a `-loops=2` flag to it, if it is a fresh SSD for benchmarking.

If you did want it to be secure you may be able to use the `-randrepeat=bool`
 option, as that will toggle "Seed the random number generator in a predictable way so results are repeatable across runs. Default: true.", but I'm still not certain how secure that would be.

Additionally some enterprise class HDDs out there are SED (Self Encrypting Drives) and will allow you to spin the encryption key to instantly and securely erasing all the data written.

Lastly, I have in the past used DBAN (aka Darik's Boot and Nuke), which has CD and USB bootable options and "is an open source project hosted on SourceForge. The program is designed to securely erase a hard disk until its data is permanently removed and no longer recoverable"

Comment: The size=100% didn't work for me, but fill_device=1 (or fill_fs=1) did.

Comment: I think thats would be dependent if your giving it a block level device or a filesystem to fill up. With the block level device it knows how big it is and the size is a percent of the device size. Where as the fill_device goes until it gets a device full error. I think the fill_device flag may not overwrite any files, just unused space. I haven't put that to the test, as I usually avoid filesystems unless necessary when I do device testing.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to fill a 4TB external USB HDD with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX status=progress` which was way too slow (irrespective of `bs=` settings), and it seems that `openssl` has a cap on how much random data it will output (at least for version 1.0.2p). The best option I found was the [comment from frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72216/fast-way-to-randomize-hd/467437#comment104583_72216) to use `shred`, as in:

`shred -v -n 1 /dev/sdX`

Make sure to use the `-n 1` otherwise it will default to writing the device 3 times over (plus the `-v` which shows progress). I don't think the quality of the [pseudo-random numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html#Random-sources) is that high, but it's enough for me to prepare a large capacity portable HDD for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck if neither the block size nor the hard drive, but the slow generation of pseudo-random numbers. `/dev/urandom` is by magnitudes faster compared to `/dev/random` since it's not blocking on a low entropy pool.

You can confirm this by measuring the raw output of your pseudo-random numbers:

```
pv /dev/urandom >/dev/null
```

This rate will be much slower than the write rate of your hard drive. A correct solution totally depends on your required level of security. If you require high security either use a [fast hardware random generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hardware_random_number_generators) or accept the slow speed. If your security needs are not that high, you could capture a few dozen MiB of data and write that string repeatedly to the drive. Or maybe even writing zeros from `/dev/zero` is an option.

#### Summary

`/dev/random`  - secure, very slow
`/dev/urandom` - <strike>less</strike> secure¹, slow
hardware RNG  - secure, fast, very expensive
(`/dev/zero`    - not random at all, very fast)

¹<sub>According to [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939) `/dev/urandom` is as secure as `/dev/random`. Thanks to Gilles for pointing this out.</sub>

Comment: He's already using `urandom`.

Comment: Indeed. My point is that even urandom is too slow for his needs that's why he needs a different solution than urandom.

Comment: [There is no added security in using `/dev/random`](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the link. The man page clearly states: […As a result, if there is not sufficient entropy in the entropy pool, the returned values are theoretically vulnerable to a cryptographic attack…](http://linux.die.net/man/4/random) That's why I classified it as less secure.

Answer (score 0):

Completing Marco's answer, what you need is faster random number generator.

You use a simple program that echos random numbers from a good library like `boost::random` and use that one in `dd`.

If you choose boost, you can use [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/random/example/random_demo.cpp) example, changing the `experiment` function to your needs.

Comment: How much faster is the boost solution on your system? A quick non-scientific benchmark on my machine yields exactly the same speed as `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: `boost::random` doesn't offer a crypto RNG, does it? If you're going to use a non-crypto RNG, you might as well use zeroes: at least you won't have an illusion of security.

Comment: I can't be specific about how much faster `boost::random` generators are, the only way to know for sure is measure their fastest algorithm against `/dev/urandom`