# DD with a specific pattern

Tags: dd, block-device

I was watching [this Defcon video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NG9Cg_vBKOg) and around 4:30 he shows a custom pattern of drive wiping — the drive is filled with a constant text pattern.

Whether he is joking or not, is this possible? How would it be done using Linux's `dd` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drive shown is filled with a repeating text pattern. This is dead easy to do. Not with `dd`, because `dd` doesn't do repeated patterns. There's [no magic in `dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days/12538#12538), it's just a tool to copy bytes in slightly weird ways, which is very occasionally useful. The magic is in the block device (e.g. `/dev/sda` for a disk or `/dev/sda1` for a partition). To generate a constant pattern, use [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes):

```
yes 'Now wouldn'\'' you like to know what was there before?' >/dev/sda
```

(Don't run this at home! This is a command to wipe your hard drive. Also, note that in order to wipe the whole drive, you'd probably have to do it from an independent live system: if you wipe the mounted disk you're running from, the system is likely to crash as it tries to load bits of files and fails.)

Comment: "yes "string of test" | tr "\n" " " > /dev/sda" if you don't like newlines.
Excellent for my purpose if writing to a fake USB to see corruption