# Full DD copy from hdd to hdd

Tags: hard-disk, dd, cloning

*ORIGINAL QUESTION:*

If I have [2 identical hard drives](http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/components-upgrades/internal-hard-drives/3-5-inch-hard-drives/wd-mainstream-3-5-internal-hard-drive-3tb-21651952-pdt.html) with the following characteristics:

- SATA 6.0 Gb/s
- 5400 rpm
- 3TB

How long should a full dd copy take to complete?

So far it's been running for 5 hours and still going...

I am using Linux Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and the command I am using is:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc
```

---

**UPDATE: 1**

I can now see the progress, and it's been 6+ hours for copy 430GB.  The HDD is 3TB...

Is there no faster way of doing this?

---

**UPDATE: 2**

This seems a lot better than before (Thanks to [Groxxda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74409/groxxda) for [the suggestions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144178/318461)):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=128K | pv -s 3000G | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc bs=128K
```

ETA is about 9 hours for 3TB, whereas before it reached 430GB after 6 hours, so I am guessing it would have taken about 36 hours using the previous command.

Comment: Try to grab the statistics of the process:  
Sending a USR1 signal to a running 'dd' process makes it print I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying.

    $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null& pid=$!
    $ kill -USR1 $pid

Check your man page for the actual signal as it differs for different dd implementations.

Comment: @Groxxda, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: GNU dd uses `SIGUSR1`, and BSD dd uses `SIGINFO`

Comment: Also what do you mean with "connected to the same sata cable"? Are you using some sort of port multiplier? (If you achieve a transfer rate of 150MB/s it should take you 5-6hrs, but I think half of that is more realistic.)

Comment: @Groxxda,  No, it's a single sata cable, which allows 2 hdds to connect to a single sata port.  It's doing 19MB/s for some reason...

Comment: You may be able to speed up the process by specifying a different (bigger) blocksize (`bs=` argument to `dd`). Also consider connecting each HDD to its own sata port.

Comment: @Groxxda, what blocksize do you recommend?

Comment: Have a look at [this thread on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/234199/good-block-size-for-disk-cloning-with-diskdump-dd). I would suggest you try a few values from 64K to 4M and see what works best for you. They also mention a flag `direct` that might speed up the copy, but I haven't used that.

Comment: What did you finally use for the other disks? dd (with direct?) ? bs? or cat was as fast? Any insight on a SATA HDD (now connected via USB) to SSD (new that is replacing the SATA HDD) ?

Comment: For good block sizes, these two questions can also be considered: https://serverfault.com/questions/147935 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`dd` was useful in the old days when people used tapes (when block sizes mattered) and when simpler tools such as `cat` might not be binary-safe.

Nowadays, `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc` is a just complicated, error-prone, [slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) way of writing `cat /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc`. While [`dd` still useful for some relatively rare tasks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days/12538#12538), it is a lot less useful than the number of tutorials mentioning it would let you believe. There is no magic in `dd`, the magic is all in `/dev/sdb`.

Your new command `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=128K | pv -s 3000G | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc bs=128K` is again needlessly slow and complicated. The data is read 128kB at a time (which is better than the `dd` default of 512B, but not as good as even larger values). It then goes through two pipes before being written.

Use the simpler and faster `cat` command. (In some [benchmarks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) I made a couple of years ago under Linux, `cat` was faster than `cp` for a copy between different disks, and `cp` was faster than `dd` with any block size; `dd` with a large block size was slightly faster when copying onto the same disk.)

```
cat /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc
```

If you want to run this command in `sudo`, you need to make the redirection happen as root:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc'
```

If you want a progress report, since you're using Linux, you can easily get one by noting the PID of the `cat` process (say 1234) and looking at the position of its input (or output) file descriptor.

```
# cat /proc/1234/fdinfo/0
pos:    64155648 
flags:  0100000
```

If you want a progress report and your unix variant doesn't provide an easy way to get at a file descriptor positions, you can install and use [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) instead of `cat`.

Comment: What is strange with large blocks is that the bottleneck is the disk, so what makes `cat` faster than `dd` ? Could it be that `cat` uses the cache ?

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the answer. I have another five 3TB drives to clone and will try the cat option next.  As far as I can tell, that new dd command is going to take another 3 hours to complete, to about 11 hours in total.  If the cat approach is faster than 11 hours for the second 3TB HDD, I will use that method for the remaining drives.

Comment: @Emmanuel Both use the cache in the same way. I don't understand why there's a significant difference between `cat`, `cp` and `dd` with a large block size (it's easy to understand why `dd` with a small block size is slower: it makes more system calls for the same amount of data).

Comment: @oshirowanen You're getting a little over 80MB/s, which sounds pretty good for a 5400rpm drive.

Comment: @Gilles, I have pv installed and am currently copying the data using the cat method you suggested.  How do I use pv to get a human readable progress report?

Comment: @gilles I was thinking : if `cat`uses the cache that will allow to read onto one disk while writing on the other. If `dd` was intended to write on tapes perhaps it bypasses the cache to have a better control.

Comment: @Gilles, so to get progress report, do I use `sudo sh -c 'pv /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc'` instead of `sudo sh -c 'cat /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc'`?

Comment: @oshirowanen Yes, use `pv` where you'd use `cat`.

Comment: @Emmanuel No, `dd` doesn't (can't) bypass the cache.

Comment: @gilles I think it can with oflag=direct but doesn't by default.

Comment: @Gilles +1 for suggesting using `cat`. Just copied a 128-Gb SSD drive, and it took only half an hour.

Comment: I have a question, If I've 2 hdd of 2TB (sdc, sdb), and want clone the firts sdc... should I put `cat /dev/sdc >/dev/sdb` ? is it secure way? Thanks!!

Comment: What happens if you do this on a multi-device btrfs fs?

Comment: @unhammer I don't know how btrfs stores information about where to find the other devices. If it's able to assemble filesystem parts from their content alone regardless of their location (like Linux LVM), then just copying one or more of the devices byte for byte will work. A robust system like btrfs should be able to do this, otherwise plugging in an external disk or restoring from a backup would be very painful.

Comment: OK, I guess it'd have to be something like `cat /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 > /dev/sdb` (given the original btrfs mount used `-odevice=/dev/sdc1,device=/dev/sdd1`). I felt a bit too unsure so I ended up waiting for `/bin/cp -a` instead, which wasn't too bad.

Comment: @unhammer No! You would copy each device one by one, e.g. `cat /dev/sdc1 >/dev/sdb1 && cat /dev/sdd1 >/dev/sde1`. Concatenating the two parts doesn't make sense. If you want to change the structure of the btrfs volume, to change it from having two subvolumes to one, you need to use btrfs tools to change the structure, or as you did to create a new filesystem with the desired structure and copy the files.

Comment: OK, had a feeling it wouldn't work exactly like that, thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Never would have thought of `cat /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc` to replace `dd`.

Answer (score 11):

`dd` uses a very small blocksize by default (512 bytes). That results in a lot of overhead (one `read()` and `write()` syscall for every 512 bytes).

It goes a lot faster when you use a larger blocksize. Optimal speeds start at `bs=64k` or so. Most people use a still larger `bs=1M` so it becomes human readable (when `dd` says it copied `1234 blocks`, you know it's `1234 MiB` without doing any math). Using even larger blocksizes are unlikely to result in speed improvements, just higher memory consumption.

So the command should be:

```
dd bs=1M if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc
```

If you already have a slow `dd` running, you can interrupt it and resume with a faster `dd` instance. For this it is important to know how far the copy progressed already. `dd` usually prints the progress when you cancel it, or you can send it the `USR1` signal while it is running to make it print its progress.

```
kill -USR1 $(pidof dd)
```

For example if it copied more than `1234MiB`, you can resume at position `1234MiB` using:

```
dd bs=1M seek=1234 skip=1234 if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc
```

If it copied fewer than `1234MiB`, your copy will be incomplete. If it copied more than `1234MiB`, it will re-copy some already copied parts, which normally does not do any harm. So if in doubt you should pick a value slightly smaller than what you believe was already copied.

Answer (score 6):

### Getting statistics about ongoing dd process

You can use the `kill` command with the appropriate signal to make `dd` output statistics to standard error.
From the GNU dd man page:

```
Sending a USR1 signal to a running 'dd' process makes it print I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying.
      $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null& pid=$!
      $ kill -USR1 $pid
      18335302+0 records in 18335302+0 records out 9387674624 bytes (9.4 GB)  copied,  34.6279 seconds, 271 MB/s
```

**Make sure you check your man page for the correct signal first as it may differ on different dd implementations:** (BSD dd uses SIGINFO).

### Speeding up the process

1. Connect each HDD to it's own SATA port so the data can be read from one device and written to the other at the same time.
2. Use an appropriate blocksize using the `bs=` argument. Have a look at [this thread on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/234199/good-block-size-for-disk-cloning-with-diskdump-dd) and try some values for yourself.
3. Use separate `dd` invocations for reading and writing and use a pipe to connect them (`dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`).
   If you do this and specify a blocksize, make sure you use the same blocksize on each invocation.
4. You may try other optimizations like the `direct` argument.
5. Make sure your hard disks are not mounted or it may result in a corrupt copy.

Comment: You can use `watch kill -USR1 $pid` or also monitor the progress like that: https://www.howtogeek.com/428654/how-to-monitor-the-progress-of-linux-commands-with-pv-and-progress/

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried 'gparted' ? You can literally copy-paste a partition from one drive to another and resize it accordingly as needed. You get transfer rate and time remaining. It uses 'e2image' underneath for linux partitions.

Comment: Note: you need to boot from a live-cd or live-usb with Ubuntu to be able to do it. Otherwise, the root host system will be blocked for copying.

Answer (score 0):

There is commercial software called [HDClone](https://www.miray.de/download/sat.hdclone.html). It is licensed as both freeware and commercial. Either version can create a bootable pendrive or DVD, as well as copying disks. Connect the source and destination HDs and follow the GUI-based instructions.

The free one will transfer at a rate about 80MB/sec, while the paid versions can go much faster. For NTFS and FAT filesystems, the paid versions can be configured to clone only the occupied bits of the HD, which dramatically increases the speed of each clone.

Comment: (1) Are you affiliated with this product? (2) Where can we get it?

Comment: Or you could just use "cat /dev/sdx > /dev/sdy" for free...