# i have linux in my hdd, how can i transfer all my linux system files to ssd. the ssd was already in my laptop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-disk, ssd

I just installed Linux Mint with dual boot (in windows). Linux is installed in Hdd and windows is installed in SSD. And I deleted windows, so now my ssd is empty. Now how can i shift my linux system files from hdd to ssd? Please Help!!

Comment: does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144172/72456

Comment: You can do it using `dd`. That being said, I'd recommend copying all your important files to an external drive, and then format and do a fresh install onto the SSD.

Comment: dd is only for same size to same size or larger. And you cannot reboot with both connected as duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs are not allowed. I would just do new install & restore from your backup. Then you have confirmed your backup includes everything you need when (not if) a drive fails. Backup should include all of /home, data (if not in /home), list of installed apps, perhaps some settings from /etc and list of installed apps. If server apps those folders in / would also need backing up.