# how to use dd to backup second linux hard drive from os x?

Tags: osx, backup, dd

I have a MacBook with Linux installed on the primary hard drive.  On an external USB 3.0 drive, I have OS X installed.

The external drive has plenty of space so I would like to boot up OS X and make regular copies of the primary drive using `dd`.

Performing the backup the other way would be simply done using something like: `dd if=/dev/sda of=/backups/backup.dmp`, however, OS X is a little alien to me, so I'm not sure how to reference the primary drive from OS X.

1. What would be the dd command line for making a backup?
2. What would be the dd command line for restoring the backup?

Comment: note that [you don't actually need `dd` for this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diskutil list
```

will show you the Drives.

A Partition is /dev/diskXsY.

So

```
dd if=/dev/diskXsY of=/BACKUPIMAGE.img
```

with the appropriate X and Y should do it for you.

Comment: I would like to backup the whole disk, so I guess it will be `dd if=/dev/diskX of=/BACKUPIMAGE.img`?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Maybe a bs=4M or so, to make it faster.