# dd command in script not running when executed from udev rule

Tags: bash, udev, raspbian, dd

I would like to setup a Raspberry Pi 3 running Rasbian to automatically copy a DVD disk when a disk is inserted in a coupled disk station. To achieve this, I have written a udevrule and a script to run when this rule is triggered.

The udev rule seems to work fine and runs the script when the disk is inserted.

The script contains the `dd` command. When i execute the script manually from the command line, it works correctly and executes the `dd`command. When the script is run by `udev` on disk insertion however, everthing in the script executes, except the `dd` command.

I have searched online but could not find anyone else with the same issue. Does someone have a clue what the problem might be?

udev rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/65-autorip.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr[0-4]", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/autorip/autorip.sh /dev/%k %E{ID_CDROM_MEDIA}"
```

disk copy script `/usr/local/bin/autorip/autorip.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# function to activate a led and eject disk when an error occurs
error(){
    python /usr/local/bin/autorip/led-on.py
    eject
}

# function to deactivate the led for
reset_led(){
    python /usr/local/bin/autorip/led-off.py
}

# if udev flag to check if disk change action is insert (second script parameter) is set
if [ $2 == "1" ]; then
    reset_led
    #use wodim command to find out if disk is DVD
    disk_info=$(wodim -atip dev='/dev/sr0')
    if [[ $disk_info = *"mmc_mdvd"* ]] ; then
            # copy disk contents to temp location (not working when ran from udev)
            dd if=/dev/sr0 of=/tmp/autorip_disk_image_$RANDOM$RANDOM.iso
            eject
    else
            error
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Is the script running as root? dd might not be executing because of permission issues.

Comment: does udev not automatically execute scripts with root privileges?

Comment: What happens if you use the full path of the `dd` command to call it?

Comment: thanks for the tip. this does however not change the result. the command still does not run

Comment: Just an FYI, [there's no need for `dd` for this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532/22222). Just use `cat`.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/49370894/1778421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`udev` rules are **not** meant for longer running tasks, like copying a DVD. From `man udev`:

> This can only be used for very short-running foreground tasks.
>              Running an event process for a long period of time may block all
>              further events for this or a dependent device.
>
> Starting daemons or other long-running processes is not appropriate
>              for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be
>              unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.

In addition, scripts executed by `udev` run in a somewhat restricted environment.

So the proper way to do this is to make an udev rule that triggers a program that was already started by the user (via D-Bus, a socket, a named pipe, or otherwise); this program can then in turn copy the DVD. This also solves the problem of giving the DVD-copying program proper permissions.

Comment: But you could use it to start systemd units. They are not forked from the process which causes the start.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Yes, any way to communicate with another program (systemd, at, socat with exec, whatever) and have it start something is fine.

Comment: `socat` does not isolate processes.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: It doesn't have to - the `socat` with the exec option isn't forked from the `udev` process, it's started beforehand. The `udev` process can use a second `socat` without exec to message the first `socat`, of course. Or it can use something else.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thank you for your answer. This was the information I needed to continue my project!

Answer (score 0):

When a script or program doesn't do what you think it should do it's time to get out the debugging tools. In the script, add the following two lines at the top to record what it is doing:

```
set -x
exec >/tmp/debug-$$.out 2>&1
```

Then it will write a log of every command executed to a debug file in the /tmp/ directory. My wild guess is that you will see that the script not only does not execute `dd` but also the `eject` command in the next line, because the `wodim` command does not see the DVD at the time the script is run by udev. That can probably be fixed by adding a sufficient `sleep` before the `wodim.`