# How to dd a local disk into a remote disk?

Tags: ssh, dd

I have a local machine that needs be migrated to remote disk. How can I do it with dd? I know local format for command

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdx count=x bs=x
```

But how to do it via ssh direct from local to remote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should run two instances of `dd` in that case, one in the local host and the other one on the remote host (through `ssh`.)

To make that work, you would omit the `of=` argument, to have `dd` write the blocks to stdout (which you can write to a pipe), or omit `if=` to read from stdin (from a pipe.)

For example, copying from local to remote:

```
dd if=/dev/sdx bs=x count=x |
    ssh user@host dd of=/dev/sdx bs=x
```

Or to copy from remote to local:

```
ssh user@host dd if=/dev/sdx bs=x count=x |
    dd of=/dev/sdx bs=x
```

You likely want to use matching `bs=` settings on both sides (though technically that's not strictly necessary.)

Comment: Thx Filbranden !!

Comment: You might find [cat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9492/117549) interesting, too!  [Also related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12538/117549)