# dd command to get data of specific range

Tags: dd

In the `dd` command, we can use `skip` to skip n byte in a file. From nth byte to end of file is copied. But I want to copy binary data from 1228 to 1331 only. 
How do I achieve this with `dd` on Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `count` to specify the number of bytes to copy. Use the shell to do the calculation. Use `ibs=1` to set the input block size to 1, so the `skip` and `count` are specified in bytes.

```
 dd ibs=1 skip=1228 count=$((1331-1228+1))
```

As 1228 and 1331-1228+1 are both multiples of 4 it would be possible to set the input block size to 4, which would make things more efficient but unless this was going to be used an enormous number of times the optimization will be lost in the noise. Other things like pre-calculating the result of `1331-1228+1` should be done first.

```
 dd ibs=4 skip=$((1228/4)) count=$(((1331-1228+1)/4))
```

Comment: Whats ibs parameter ?

Comment: @AashishPawar answer expanded to explain a little about ibs.

Answer (score 0):

[There's no reason to use `dd` at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532/22222). A simple `head` and `tail` combination is enough (requires GNU tools) :

```
head -c 1331 file | tail -c $((1331-1228+1))
```

Comment: probably -c not -n

Comment: @frostschutz whoops, thanks. I was testing with - n on my machine.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick true, I forgot to mention that, but the OP is on Linux.

Comment: The OP is on linux, but you edit the question to delete the linux tag, but your answer depends on common linux extensions??? Perhaps you should revert your edit.

Comment: @icarus argh, you're quite right, sorry! I removed the tag because tags shouldn't be used to specify the OS (the `linux` tag would be next to useless in this site since the vast majority of questions are from people running Linux), but I stupidly forgot to add it to the question! Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score -1):

just finished an common script dd-file-range.sh:
[dd-file-range.sh](https://github.com/tcler/kiss-vm-ns/blob/master/utils/dd-file-range.sh)

used to copy of a byte range from one file to another.
like syscall copy_file_range(2) on linux kernel-5.3 or FreeBSD-13
see also: [linux copye_file_range()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) and [FreeBSD copy_file_range()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=copy_file_range&sektion=2&n=1)

and could also use the xfs_io->copy_range sub-command in newer linux  distributions instead dd-file-range.sh

Usage:

```
$ dd-file-range.sh
Usage: dd-file-range.sh <ifile[:skip_offset[:len]]> [ofile[:seek_offset]] [-bs=BSIZE] [-sep=<seperator>] [-log=<0|1|2>]
#Comment: if 'skip_offset' start with '['; trate it as 'start' #((start=skip_offset+1))
#Comment: if 'len' has a suffix ']'; trate it as 'end' #((end=skip_offset+len))
#Comment: e.g: ifile:5:5 <=is equivalent to=> ifile:[6:10]

Examples:
  dd-file-range.sh ifile:8192:512  ofile
  dd-file-range.sh ifile::4096     ofile:1024
  dd-file-range.sh ifile:4                     #output to stdout
  dd-file-range.sh <(cat):4  ofile             #read from stdin
  dd-file-range.sh ifile::4  ifile:10          #copy data within same file
```

for the original question, we can use dd-file-range.sh like:

```
$ dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm:$((1228-1)):$((1331-1228+1))
$ #or simple
$ dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm:[1228:1331]
```

performance test with different bs:

```
$ ls -lh kiss-vm.gif 
-rw-r--r-- 1 yjh fs-qe 4.0M May 12  2021 kiss-vm.gif
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=$((128*1024))
real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.026s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=$((64*1024))
real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.022s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old #default BS == $((16*1024))
real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.025s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=$((8*1024))
real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.023s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=$((4*1024))
real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.022s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=1024
real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.028s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=512
real    0m0.039s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.048s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=256
real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.010s
sys 0m0.044s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=128
real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.057s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=64
real    0m0.072s
user    0m0.011s
sys 0m0.102s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=32
real    0m0.129s
user    0m0.014s
sys 0m0.199s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=16
real    0m0.275s
user    0m0.049s
sys 0m0.425s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=8
real    0m0.460s
user    0m0.077s
sys 0m0.707s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=4
real    0m1.278s
user    0m0.208s
sys 0m2.082s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=2
real    0m1.841s
user    0m0.294s
sys 0m2.846s
$ time dd-file-range.sh kiss-vm.gif:1981 b:1981 -ver=old -bs=1
real    0m3.924s
user    0m0.610s
sys 0m6.227s
```

Comment: What does this program do? There's nothing even on the GitHub link that explains what it does or why someone should need to use it

Comment: Despite the recent edit, you still don't explain  what it does or why someone should need to use it

Comment: thanks @roaima for your patience, edit/update again :) added more instructions and updated the script.

Comment: This shell script is just an overly complicated bash shell script wrapper around `dd`

Comment: @fpmurphy Yes, and it provides an extremely simple user interface