# Is `dd` the universal way to create a bootable flash drive for Debian or (L)Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, system-installation, bootable

I have found various ways of creating a bootable USB flash drive for (L)ubuntu and Debian.

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/377561 says to create a bootable Ubuntu USB
   flash drive from terminal, run

   ```
   sudo dd bs=4M if=path/to/input.iso of=/dev/sd<?> conv=fdatasync  status=progress
   ```
2. https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.en.html says

   > The CD or DVD image you choose should be written directly to the USB stick, overwriting its current contents. For example, when using
   >   an existing GNU/Linux system, the CD or DVD image file can be
   >   written to a USB stick as follows, after having made sure that the
   >   stick is unmounted:

   ```
   # cp debian.iso /dev/sdX
   # sync
   ```
3. debian: [Creating a Bootable Debian USB Flashdrive](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstall#Creating_a_Bootable_Debian_USB_Flashdrive) says

   > To create a bootable USB drive from Windows, Mac OS, or a preexisting GNU/Linux installation, a reliable choice is to use
   >   Rufus.
4. Lubuntu: [Writing/burning the Image](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.2/booting_the_image.html#writing-burning-the-image) says:

   > For writing images to USB drives on Linux, we recommend `mkusb` a tool developed by a Lubuntu team member, or the USB creator shipped
   >   with Lubuntu Startup Disk Creator .

I was wondering if the first way by `dd` which works at block level can work in all the cases?
Is it the universal way?

Why can the second way  use `cp` which works at file level not block level?

What are the benefits of the other ways compared to the first way of using `dd`? Can I achieve the same of the other ways, by using `dd` or some other commands along using `dd`?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no point in using `dd`, `cp` will do the job as well. What does `on block level` mean for you?

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days

Comment: Some tools like [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) or [rufus](https://rufus.ie/) have an option to create a secondary partition for persistent storage (doesn't work with all distros). You can of course do this manually, i.e. partition your USB stick, create a `persistence.conf` if needed, etc.

Comment: You have to define what "working at block level" and "working at file level" mean here.

Comment: @mosvy partition/device level and file system level.

Comment: One can also use `cat debian.iso > /dev/sdX` which is what I do when creating bootable USBs

Comment: @NasirRiley Thanks. What is special about Startup Disk Creator, Rufus and mksub?

Comment: They are just GUI (or in the case of mkusb, interactive) tools for people who prefer to do it that way. Think of it as the difference between `gparted` and `parted` in the terminal. Same thing, different ways.

Comment: This is actually a great question, and is one of the top hits on google when you search for this problem. It's sad that the format of StackExchange is such that difficult problems have no place here. No one has linked a genuine duplicate of this question for reference of seekers.

I have never, not a single time, had 'cp', 'dd', or any other copy method actually work in creating a bootable USB. Computers ditched standard CD drives almost 10 years ago, and creating a bootable USB is still a headache. I'm not an idiot. I know how to dispatch 'cp' and 'sync' commands. But, it  doesn't work IRL!

Answer (score 2):

In Unix/Linux, a device is handled just like a regular file. If you place data on the device by using cp(1), or dd(1), or `program > /dev/sdb` makes no real difference. Just that e.g. dd has options for writing out in different sized chunks, that can be more efficient if the block size matches some hardware defined size.

Comment: Thanks. What is special about  Startup Disk Creator, Rufus and mkusb?