# Piping dd with pishrink and ssh to remotely create a shrunk backup image

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dd

I usually create remote backup image of my raspberrypi from my macbook by using:

```
ssh pi@xx.x.x.xx "sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M” | pv | gzip - | dd of=/Users/USER/Downloads/pibackup.gz
```

There are drawbacks but It works quite fine and i'm ok with it.
Recently i found [pishrink](https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink) and i would like to include it in the aforementioned pipe maybe removing gzip since pishrink can do it itself.
So first think i installed pyshrink on my raspberry and then i tried to run something like

```
ssh pi@xx.x.x.xx "sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M status=progress | pishrink.sh -az -"| dd of=/Users/USER/Downloads/pibackup.img.gz
```

But it doesn't work.
Does anyone got some suggestion?

Comment: Note that you don't need `dd` at all. You could just do `ssh pi@xx.x.x.xx "sudo cat /dev/mmcblk0 | pv | gzip - > /Users/USER/Downloads/pibackup.gz`. See [dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532)

Comment: That said, please [edit] your question and tell us _how_ it failed. Did nothing happen? Did you get an error message? Was a file created? What was wrong with the file? "It doesn't work" gives us no information to understand what happened.

Comment: @terdon Ok i will update the question with the error message.
PS
is there a " missing in the command you just posted?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't close the `"`. I just wanted to point out that you don't need `dd` and you probably should avoid it since its syntax makes it very easy to make a horrible mistake. Also, you should probably do the compression on the pi instead of locally. No reason to transfer the uncompressed data over the network.