Is dd the best way to write an image to a drive?
I'm using this pipeline to write an image file to drive $drive:
wget -o logfile -O - https://route/to/image.gz | \
         gunzip -c | \
         dd of="$drive" bs=4M conv=fdatasync 2>/dev/null

logfile is created to track progress.
I've got a bad feeling about this, and can't convince myself that it's foolproof. The image itself is always a multiple of 4MB, so that's not an issue, but dd is potentially problematic (see this U&L answer, for example).
Am I being paranoid, or is there a better way to do this?
EDIT
Following the comments (thanks), I benchmarked head -c and dd bs=1 for writing an image to a drive. TL;DR: dd is basically pointless in this application. The image on the remote server gzips down to about 46M, so dd is used with bs=1, so this is perhaps a little unfair to dd. The image is retrieved with wget, gunzip'ed on the fly, and then written to the drive with either head -c or dd bs=1:
Option 1:
# time wget -o logfile -O - https://path/to/foo.img.gz | \
       gunzip -c | \
       dd of=/dev/sda bs=1 conv=fdatasync 2>/dev/null
    real    1m55.665s
    user    0m32.323s
    sys     2m20.841s

Option 2:
# time wget -o logfile -O - https://path/to/foo.img.gz | \
       gunzip -c | \
       cat > /dev/sda 2>/dev/null
    real    0m7.419s
    user    0m0.646s
    sys     0m0.507s

Both options were tested by getting the md5sum and sha256sum of the first 48159047 bytes of the drive, and both gave the correct pre-compression md5sum and sha256sum as found on the server:
# time head -c 48159047 /dev/sda | md5sum
b3df12b61df3121ad112f825cc6fe8b7  -

real    0m0.222s
user    0m0.075s
sys     0m0.049s

# time dd status=none if=/dev/sda bs=1 count=48159047 | md5sum
b3df12b61df3121ad112f825cc6fe8b7  -

real    1m31.627s
user    0m49.218s
sys     1m45.406s

The sha256sum results were much the same: about 0.25s real time for head -c, and 1m32s for dd.

See: dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532/170373

The dd block size is only an issue if you limit the number blocks to process. 10x8192B blocks may not be 81920 B.

@ilkkachu dd is still relevant if you need to start reading/writing in the middle of a file. It is also able to do some conversions that cat wouldn't be able to perform.

@ilkkachu Silly me, that was the title of the question you linked to, not an actual question posed by you in your comment. Mea culpa.

A better way? Without changing the process which creates the image? Without any detail on how the image is created? Without replacing your current of images?.....

Is $drive the name of the whole drive, or a partition? E.g. /dev/sda or /dev/sda1. If it's the whole disk, (/dev/sda), you run the risk of overwriting the GPT or MBR at the beginning of the disk. dd can be told to skip blocks, see man dd.

@waltinator: whole drive, overwrites everything. It's a bootable image.

@symcbean: it doesn't really matter what the image file is; the intention is just to overwrite the (start of) the drive. I don't have a problem with creating the image; I just want to make sure it's correctly written to the drive.

What does "best" mean?  Do you mean fastest? Least error prone?  Least impact on system performance?  Any possible answer to this would probably be opinion based or already covered by other questions already linked in comments.

This question is similar to: dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There's no need for a backslash after an incomplete pipeline (eg. instead of the first line being wget -o ... | \ , it can be wget -o ... |). Just make sure the line in question is an incomplete pipeline, in other words it ends with a pipe character |.

Personally I think ddrescue is much better. It is dd, but handles better failures (so if you are doing a dd because you have some errors on old drive, better to use the modified version. (In past with floppy disks it was also more necessary).

dd is a simple raw interface to the read() and write() system calls.
In:

dd of="$drive" bs=4M conv=fdatasync`


You're telling dd to do n = read(0, buf, 4*1024*1024), followed by write(outfd, buf, n).
However read() on a pipe typically returns how many bytes there currently is in the pipe buffer, or the requested size if that's less, but a pipe buffer on Linux is 64KiB by default, so here the blocks that dd will read and write will be of varying size which will depend on how gunzip writes its output to the pipe, and how fast dd will empty the pipe.
Using strace, I see that my gunzip writes its output in blocks of 32KiB which is a divisor of the pipe size. It's likely initially dd will be much faster to read from the pipe than gunzip will be to write to it, so most likely the read and writes will be of 32KiB.
When the kernel buffers for $drive are going to be full (assuming $drive is slower to write to than gunzip is to decompress the data which is likely) after a few hundred mebibytes, dd will be slowed down, and gunzip will be able to fill the pipe (and be slowed down as well as a result). Then you'll see dd writing blocks of 64KiB (the size of the pipe buffer).
Unless you enlarge the pipe buffer size, the writes will never be of 4MiB. For that, you'd need iflag=fullblock for dd to do as many read()s as needed to fill up a 4MiB block before writing it.
In any case, the only thing useful in that command is the conv=fdatasync which does a fdatasync(outfd) in the end to make sure that when dd exits, all the data has been flushed to disk and explains the timing difference (in the cat case, the system will carry on writing to disk long after cat has returned), but  the read+write loop that dd (or cat) does is completely unnecessary overhead.
Here, you could do:
{
  wget -o logfile -O - https://route/to/image.gz | gunzip
  </dev/null dd conv=fdatasync status=none
} > "$drive

Where gunzip writes directly to the block device (in 32KiB blocks with my gunzip and stdbuf -o4M makes no difference), and dd does the flush in the end.
Note another advantage with that syntax is that if $drive can't be opened for writing, wget is not started and the file (the beginning of it at least) not downloaded for nothing.
For errors (by wget, gunzip, dd and the opening of the output file) to be reported in the exit status, so that you get a success code iff the data was successfully downloaded, uncompressed and written to disk:
(
  set -o pipefail
  ret=0
  wget -o logfile -O - https://route/to/image.gz | gunzip || ret=$?
  </dev/null dd conv=fdatasync status=none || ret=$?
  exit "$ret"
) > "$drive

Above still calling a fdatasync() if wget or gunzip failed, but you could also simplify it to:
(
  set -o pipefail
  wget -o logfile -O - https://route/to/image.gz | gunzip &&
    </dev/null dd conv=fdatasync status=none
) > "$drive

To skip the fdatasync() if wget or gunzip fails.
